# Rolling m out of n most recent occurences of condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm interested in the **number 'm' times within the last 'n' events that a condition is met, grouped by person or user**. Specifically, I'm interested in whether a player is used to playing in a given class, or 'category', based on how many of *their* last few matches (rather than any matches) were played at or above a specified level.

I've dutifully broken one group out of a toy dataset to work on, and got my code, below, to work. However, when I try to casually use that same chain of methods on the `SeriesGroupBy` object, things break down.

First, the simplest example. The column `hc` (high class) is `1` when 2 of the player's 3 previous matches were in category 3. Otherwise, it's 0. (I manually generated this and used 0|1, rather than True|False.):

```py
import pandas as pd
pd.__version__
# '0.23.4'
match = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c',
         'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e']
category = [3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2]
player = ['bar', 'baz', 'chaz', 'baz', 'choo', 'chaz', 'chaz', 'foo',
          'baz', 'choo', 'foo', 'char', 'baz', 'choo', 'foo', 'chaz', 'baz']
hc = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
games = pd.DataFrame({'match': match, 'category': category, 'player': player, 'hc': hc})
games

#    match  category player  hc
# 0      a         3    bar   0
# 1      a         3    baz   0
# 2      a         3   chaz   0
# 3      b         2    baz   0
# 4      b         2   choo   0
# 5      b         2   chaz   0
# 6      c         3   chaz   0
# 7      c         3    foo   0
# 8      c         3    baz   0
# 9      c         3   choo   0
# 10     d         3    foo   0
# 11     d         3   char   0
# 12     d         3    baz   1
# 13     e         2   choo   0
# 14     e         2    foo   1
# 15     e         2   chaz   1
# 16     e         2    baz   1
```

Sufficiently stymied by my lengthy prior efforts, I adopted the (apparently naive) strategy of breaking out an interesting player and getting the calculation to work on the split-out group:

```py
baz = games.groupby('player').get_group('baz')
baz

#    match  category player  hc
# 1      a         3    baz   0
# 3      b         2    baz   0
# 8      c         3    baz   0
# 12     d         3    baz   1
# 16     e         2    baz   1

result = baz.category.gt(2).rolling(3).sum().shift().gt(1)
result

# 1     False
# 3     False
# 8     False
# 12     True
# 16     True
# Name: category, dtype: bool
```

Success! I am a pandas hacker! I have ascended and can now tutor others in The Pandoric Way! Let me run a quick check, first, before I buy my robes and receive my assigned cot at the monastery:

```py
games.groupby('player').category.gt(2).rolling(3).sum().shift().gt(1)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "(boring path stuff)/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 762, in **getattr**
>       return self._make_wrapper(attr)
>     File "(boring path stuff)/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 799, in _make_wrapper
>       raise AttributeError(msg)
>   AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'gt' of 'SeriesGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method

Ugh. I am rabble.

**What's the pandorable way to do this?** Also, what have I done wrong? At a meta level, why did my strategy of operating on a single group and then generalizing not work? I did attempt the `apply()` way. It output nonsense.

EDIT: Possible answer with `apply()`:

```py
games['actual_hc'] =
    games.groupby('player').category.apply(lambda x: x.shift().gt(2).rolling(3).sum().fillna(0, downcast='infer').astype(int).gt(1))
games

#    match  category player  hc  actual_hc
# 0      a         3    bar   0      False
# 1      a         3    baz   0      False
# 2      a         3   chaz   0      False
# 3      b         2    baz   0      False
# 4      b         2   choo   0      False
# 5      b         2   chaz   0      False
# 6      c         3   chaz   0      False
# 7      c         3    foo   0      False
# 8      c         3    baz   0      False
# 9      c         3   choo   0      False
# 10     d         3    foo   0      False
# 11     d         3   char   0      False
# 12     d         3    baz   1       True
# 13     e         2   choo   0      False
# 14     e         2    foo   1       True
# 15     e         2   chaz   1       True
# 16     e         2    baz   1       True
```

This takes about 12s on my actual 250k-row DataFrame. I'd still love something faster, just to know "the right way," if there is one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently revisited this question and discovered the answer, `transform()`. For some reason, the answer with `apply()` by pj.dewitte is insensitive to the min_periods argument of `rolling()`, no matter how hard I pressed the keys when I typed `min_periods=2`.

The full answer:

```py
games['actual_hc'] = \
    games.groupby('player').category.transform(
        lambda g:
        g.gt(2).rolling(3, min_periods=2).sum().shift().gt(1)).astype(int)
#    match  category player  hc  actual_hc
# 0      a         3    bar   0          0
# 1      a         3    baz   0          0
# 2      a         3   chaz   0          0
# 3      b         2    baz   0          0
# 4      b         2   choo   0          0
# 5      b         2   chaz   0          0
# 6      c         3   chaz   0          0
# 7      c         3    foo   0          0
# 8      c         3    baz   0          0
# 9      c         3   choo   0          0
# 10     d         3    foo   0          0
# 11     d         3   char   0          0
# 12     d         3    baz   1          1
# 13     e         2   choo   0          0
# 14     e         2    foo   1          1
# 15     e         2   chaz   1          1
# 16     e         2    baz   1          1
```

Note that, even though `foo` has only had two matches prior to her final match, they were both class three, and she is correctly reported as being a high class player at `games.iloc[14]`.

Answer (score 0):

Using apply:

```
games.groupby('player').apply(
    lambda group: group.category.gt(2).rolling(3).sum().shift().gt(1)
)
```

This outputs:

```
player    
bar     0     False
baz     1     False
        3     False
        8     False
        12     True
        16     True
char    11    False
chaz    2     False
        5     False
        6     False
        15     True
choo    4     False
        9     False
        13    False
foo     7     False
        10    False
        14    False
Name: category, dtype: bool
```

which seems to be what you want.

I don't know whether this is performance-wise the best, but since the error suggests using apply, I'm guessing the developers of pandas think this is a good idea.

Comment: Not quite! Two of foo's previous games are at category 3 in row 14.